# TxtSaludo cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, field

I'm doing a simple Android project where you write your name in a field and it tells you:

> *Hello + (your name)!*

But I get 2 errors in the Java Files.

This is the code from the Java file.

```
package com.example.dontworry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Inicio extends Activity {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //ERROR 1
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView txtSaludo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtSaludo);
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        txtSaludo.setText("Hola " + b.getString("Nombre"));
    }
}
```

**ERROR 1: TxtSaludo cannot be resolved or is not a field**

And this is the Main file:

```
package com.example.dontworry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btn_hola(View v) {
        final EditText txtNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtNombre); //ERROR 2
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("Nombre", txtNombre.getText().toString());
        i.setClass(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

**ERROR 2: TxtNombre cannot be resolved or is not a field**

Thank you very much. If you want the .xml files, I will post them (Anyway those haven't got errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in your Layouts if the TextField are defined. Because you need defined to implement the reference in your activity.

Example:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TxtSaludo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't messed around with Android in a while, but from my understanding.. You have not created/misspelled the views TxtNombre or TxtSaludo. Double check where ever you created those views and see if they are typed the same.